# Calculate Average cost Price every new date based on hte Stock

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

i'm trying to create a query in Access to calculates for all records the Average Cost price of another query that contains multiple stock buy and sell on a range of dates .

The Average Cost Price formula in T0 is: ((Accumulated Position T-1 * Av Cost Px T-1) + Qtty T0* Price T0)/ (Accumulated Position T-1+ Qtty T0)

If the record is a Sell, I just subtract the quantity of the Accumulated Position and maintain the Average Cost

I cant use sub query for it because i would have to get a record on the same column for the same query, so its impossible. I'm actually lost on how i would do that, bcse I have around 30.000 records on stock trading that I need the average cost price for each date. What is the best path to follow on that case?

```
SELECT qry_sample_data_excel_summ.Date, qry_sample_data_excel_summ.Ticker, qry_sample_data_excel_summ.buy_sell, qry_sample_data_excel_summ.SumOfQuantity AS Qtty, qry_sample_data_excel_summ.AvPrice AS Price, (SELECT Sum(Dupe.SumOfQuantity)
FROM qry_sample_data_excel_summ AS Dupe
WHERE ((Dupe.Date)<qry_sample_data_excel_summ.Date) AND ((Dupe.Ticker)=qry_sample_data_excel_summ.Ticker)) AS [Acumm_Position T-1], "?" AS Av_Cost_Px
FROM qry_sample_data_excel_summ
GROUP BY qry_sample_data_excel_summ.Date, qry_sample_data_excel_summ.Ticker, qry_sample_data_excel_summ.buy_sell, qry_sample_data_excel_summ.SumOfQuantity, qry_sample_data_excel_summ.AvPrice, "?";
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Date</th><th>Ticker</th><th>buy_sell</th><th>Qtty</th><th>Price</th><th>Acumm_Position T-1</th><th>Av_Cost_Px</th></tr><tr><td>2-Jan-20</td><td>BA</td><td>B</td><td>17,000</td><td>333.00</td><td> </td><td>333.00</td></tr><tr><td>2-Jan-20</td><td>BA</td><td>S</td><td>(5,000)</td><td>332.36</td><td> </td><td>333.00</td></tr><tr><td>2-Jan-20</td><td>KHC</td><td>B</td><td>4,000</td><td>31.64</td><td> </td><td>31.64</td></tr><tr><td>3-Jan-20</td><td>BA</td><td>B</td><td>1,000</td><td>330.53</td><td>12,000</td><td>332.81</td></tr><tr><td>3-Jan-20</td><td>BA</td><td>S</td><td>(2,000)</td><td>333.74</td><td>12,000</td><td>332.81</td></tr><tr><td>6-Jan-20</td><td>BA</td><td>B</td><td>1,000</td><td>328.32</td><td>11,000</td><td>332.44</td></tr><tr><td>6-Jan-20</td><td>BA</td><td>S</td><td>(7,000)</td><td>334.45</td><td>11,000</td><td>332.44</td></tr><tr><td>6-Jan-20</td><td>KHC</td><td>B</td><td>4,000</td><td>31.09</td><td>4,000</td><td>31.37</td></tr><tr><td>7-Jan-20</td><td>BA</td><td>S</td><td>(5,000)</td><td>341.56</td><td>5,000</td><td>324.83</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be quite helpful.

Comment: Hi Gordon, sorry i'm new to the forum. I've just added the table and desired result (last column) to the initial post. ty

Comment: still confusing.  question still needs the desired result.